# Inconsistent mouse cursor status while typing

Tags: 10.10, mouse, cursor

I have noticed that when I type in some programs, Text Editor, Terminal, Bluefish, Gnome Baker, etc. the mouse cursor disappears while I am typing.  In other programs like Firefox and LibreOffice, it does not.

I am not an application programmer, but I imagined it has to do with their cross-platform nature and the way they are compiled or the toolkits they use.  Then I noticed that Gnome-Do behaves the same way, the cursor stays on screen while typing.

Why is there inconsistent handling of the mouse cursor, while typing, across different applications?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it is just how a designer decided to write the application there are no set rules for whether a cursor should hide or not.

Comment: I guess I was hoping it was more of a global setting like the "Hide mouse cursor when typing" check-box in the control panel mouse applet on my Windows computer at work. Thanks.